# Joomla Page Redirects Incorrectly

Tags: url, redirect, iis, joomla

## Question for stackoverflow

I'm running Joomla on IIS 10 and I'm getting a URL redirecting to a non-existent page. The URL

```
http://www.website.com/pages-2/xmlogin-2
```

gets redirected to

```
https://www.website.com/https://w
```

The rewrite rules in web.config are:

```
<rewrite>
       <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Joomla! Rule 1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(>|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(&lt;|%3E)" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="_REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="CustomResponse" url="index.php" statusCode="403" statusReason="Forbidden" statusDescription="Forbidden" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Joomla! Rule 2" enabled="true">
                <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/index.php" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="website.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>     
       </rules>
   </rewrite>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Same question: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/646432/problem-redirecting-url-in-joomla-on-iis.html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/646432/problem-redirecting-url-in-joomla-on-iis.html).

Comment: You don't ever need to write **Question for stackoverflow** when you post your question in Stack Overflow -- we know where we are.  `^(.*)$` is exactly the same as `.*`, right?  Have you isolated which rule creates trouble?